# rounding a number to the hundredth place

Tags: java, jframe, rounding

I want to round the output to the hundredth place but have failed to do so.

Here is the code:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class Assignment2Part2 extends JFrame{ 


//window
private static final int WIDTH = 550;
private static final int HEIGHT = 400;
    
private JLabel firstNameL, lastNameL, milesL, costL, mpgL, dailycostL;//labels for all the variables
private JTextField firstNameTF, lastNameTF, milesTF, costTF, mpgTF, dailycostTF;//text fields for all the variables
private JButton calculateB, exitB;

private CalculateButtonHandler cbHandler;
private ExitButtonHandler ebHandler;

    
public Assignment2Part2 ()
{
 
    setTitle("Find your daily cost of driving");
    
//labels
    firstNameL = new JLabel("First Name ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lastNameL = new JLabel("Last Name ",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    milesL = new JLabel("Total miles driven per day ",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    costL = new JLabel("Cost per gallon of gas ",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    mpgL = new JLabel("Average MPG ",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    dailycostL = new JLabel("Daily cost of driving is: ",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    
//text fields
    firstNameTF = new JTextField();
    lastNameTF = new JTextField();
    milesTF = new JTextField();
    costTF = new JTextField();
    mpgTF = new JTextField();
    dailycostTF = new JTextField();
    
//find button
    calculateB = new JButton("Find");
    cbHandler = new CalculateButtonHandler();
    calculateB.addActionListener(cbHandler);
    
//exit button
    exitB = new JButton("Exit");
    ebHandler = new ExitButtonHandler();
    exitB.addActionListener(ebHandler);
    
    Container pane = getContentPane();
    
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 4));
    
//panes
    pane.add(firstNameL);
    pane.add(firstNameTF);
    pane.add(lastNameL);
    pane.add(lastNameTF);
    pane.add(milesL);
    pane.add(milesTF);
    pane.add(costL);
    pane.add(costTF);
    pane.add(mpgL);
    pane.add(mpgTF);
    pane.add(dailycostL);
    pane.add(dailycostTF);
    pane.add(calculateB);
    pane.add(exitB);
    
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

//find button
    private class CalculateButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
        //variables 
            double first, last, total, cost, averagempg, dailycost; 
        
        //strings to doubles
            total = Double.parseDouble(milesTF.getText());
            cost = Double.parseDouble(costTF.getText());
            averagempg = Double.parseDouble(mpgTF.getText());
        //calculates cost
            dailycost = (total * cost)/averagempg;
        //outputs text
            dailycostTF.setText("$" + dailycost);
        }
    }
//exit button
    private class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }           
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Assignment2Part2 rectObject = new Assignment2Part2();
    }
}
```

the output line being

```
dailycostTF.setText("$" + dailycost);
```

Any help would be great! I am completely new to Java.

Comment: What happened instead when you "failed to do so"? Furthermore, there's nothing *anywhere* in your code that looks like an attempt to round anything.

Comment: You can print out the value of a `double` rounded to a number of decimal places, but you can't set its value to round to a specific number of decimal places.

Comment: @LouisWasserman So before the `dailycostTF.setText("$" + dailycost);` would I be able to print it into this area or do I have to look else where in the program to change or round?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way is to use either the number format or decimal format class.

```
    NumberFormat dollars = new NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
```

Then you can format numbers into dollars quite easily. No clunky "$" needed.

Comment: so if I were to use this where abouts would I place this. Sorry total nooby. @Bloomfield

Comment: No worries, I was in the same spot as you a month or two ago! So first instantiate the object and then you can call the format method onto dailycost. To format dailycost, it's dollars.format(dailycost). That formats into $#.## automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");      
dailyCost = Double.valueOf(df.format(dailyCost));
```

Comment: completely inapplicable to this question.

Comment: @chrylis The OP wants to convert it to the nearest 100th num, so whats the issue with it?

Comment: The hundredth *place*, not the nearest *hundred*: 31.237 -> 31.24.